Is it possible to write a "isAlertDisplayed" method on a separate AlertHelper file?
I am trying to write a "isAlertDisplayed" method on a separate AlertHelper file using Playwright TypeScript. My test scenario is when a button is clicked for 5 seconds there is no alert.
It is the test of "On button click, alert will appear after 5 seconds" at link. when you click the button alert doesn't appear for 5 seconds. I want to verify that:

the alert is not there at the fourth second
the alert there after the fifth second.
I couldn't find proper examples to do it on the internet. and asked even ChatGPT but the solution shared is also not working.

My page parameter is passed through a PageManager instance and Page Object instances are created and returned by PageManager object pm.
Here is how I call my method:
// Verifying alert is not displayed after 4 seconds
const isAlertPresent1 = await pm.AlertHelper().isAlertDisplayed(4000);
expect(isAlertPresent1).toBe(false);

// Verifying alert is displayed after waiting for another 2 seconds
const isAlertPresent2 = await pm.AlertHelper().isAlertDisplayed(2000,true);
expect(isAlertPresent2).toBe(true);

And the method provided by ChatGPT which does not work is as follows:
async isAlertDisplayed(timeout: number = 1000, dismissAlert: boolean = true): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
        // Add an event listener for the dialog event
        const alertPromise = new Promise<boolean>(resolve => {
            this.page.once('dialog', async dialog => {
                if (dismissAlert) {
                    await dialog.dismiss(); // Dismiss the alert to allow further actions if needed
                }
                resolve(true);
            });
        });

        // Wait for the specified timeout period
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));

        // Check if the alert was displayed during the timeout period
        return await Promise.race([alertPromise, Promise.resolve(false)]);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error checking for alert:', error);
        return false;
    }
}

Any idea how to implement such method? It is a very simple function browser.isAlertOpen() in WebdriverIO but very difficult to write in Playwright. Couldn't find any sample code or methods on internet.

@ggorlen it is the test of "On button click, alert will appear after 5 seconds" at link. when you click the button alert doesn't appear for 5 seconds. I want to verify that:

the alert is not there at the fourth second
the alert there after the fifth second.

I couldn't find proper examples to do it on the internet. and asked even ChatGPT but the solution shared is also not working.

OK, good start but how can I use isAlertDisplayed? I need all the code you have so I can run a site and a test suite and actually help. Please take a moment to read the [mcve] link -- "Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself".

problem itself is this method not working. if you like to reproduce, just call that from a playwright method. go to the page click that button and call the method as I did. nothing else needed.

OK, close enough, I can work with this. Thanks. I see the page is https://demoqa.com/alerts which is reproducible--I'll answer when I have time.

ChatGPT has the right idea but is missing a critical step: removing the page.on("dialog" listener before resolving the promise. If the listener is not removed, then it leaks and the first call's handler intercepts the dialog even though it already rejected, causing the second call to throw Error: dialog.dismiss: Cannot dismiss dialog which is already handled!.
The solution is to remove the listener if the timeout happens before the dialog:
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.42.1

const waitForDialog = async (page, timeout): Promise<boolean> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const handleDialog = async dialog => {
      await dialog.dismiss();
      resolve(true);
    };
    page.once("dialog", handleDialog);
    setTimeout(() => {
      page.off("dialog", handleDialog);
      resolve(false);
    }, timeout);
  });
};

test("clicking button shows alert after 5 seconds", async ({page}) => {
  test.setTimeout(10_000)
  const url = "https://demoqa.com/alerts";
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const dialogPromise = waitForDialog(page, 4000);
  await page.locator("#timerAlertButton").click();
  expect(await dialogPromise).toBe(false);
  expect(await waitForDialog(page, 2000)).toBe(true);
});

Comment out page.off to reproduce the bug.
You can modify this to be a single call, something like waitForDialog(page, {begin: 4000, end: 6000}): throw or reject with false if an alert goes off before begin, as well as if end is exceeded. And/or make it a custom matcher.
Note that because web page timing is a fickle thing, you might want to give a bit more leeway for the dialog than 2 seconds.
Maybe someday there'll be a promise-based dialog handler in Playwright like waitForDialog. It'll be easier to do this then.

The tests passes when I copy your code. But is it not possible to watch exactly verify what's going on by eye? I tried to run npx playwright test --ui but it shows nothing about the alert is on page after 6 secs.
another thing is I don't understand why waitForDialog is assigned to a variable and written before the click. I prefer a "single line for single step/verification" mentality on my frameworks or tests as much as possible. Playwright is very strange on this perspective.

You could try slowing things down or single-stepping. Playwright runs quickly and I'm not sure offhand how it renders dialogs in the test ui. If you click first before waiting for the dialog, then you'll miss the dialog appearing. The event fires when the dialog first appears--it doesn't check whether an existing dialog is already there. Now, in this case, the dialog is supposed to fire later on, but we want to avoid a false positive when the dialog appears instantly, which is the common case when dialogs show up after clicking.

Asserting dialogs is a pretty rare thing, particularly delayed dialogs, so I don't see a big deal with Playwright not being well-suited to this particular case. Most modern sites don't use dialogs in the first place.

Another revenge DV. Answer works perfectly fine.

Makes sense. Thanks. :)
